# jade template engine, how to use layout.jade?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I have a website in node.js; to create a page, say `mypage` I noticed I need to create both a `layout.jade` and `mypage.jade` files. If I put code in `mypage.jade` it is not displayed, so first I have to fill `layout.jade` with the layout of the page.

My question is, how do I reference inside `layout.jade` that I would like to load the content of `mypage.jade` in a certain container, for example? Can I have different pages with the same layout? How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, sorry for not mentioning it. I'm using Express.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

http://expressjs.com/guide.html#view-rendering

If you don't want to use layouts you can disable them globally:

```
app.set('view options', {
  layout: false
});
```

If you don't do that layouts are enabled by default and Express searches for the standard layout in your_view_folder/layout.jade

You can specify a separate layout for each route though:

```
res.render('page', { layout: 'mylayout.jade' }); 
// you can omit .jade if you set the view engine to jade
```

Here's how your layout file could be:

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
  head
    title Testing 123
  body
    div!= body
```

Note that body will be taken from "mypage.jade".

**Edit**:

Here's a real example in an application:

The application file (containing routes and configs): 
https://github.com/alexyoung/nodepad/blob/master/app.js

The layout file: 
https://github.com/alexyoung/nodepad/blob/master/views/layout.jade

Comment: Right now what I'm doing is `res.render(__dirname+'/pages/index.jade', {user: usr});`, so what you are saying is to give to the object that wraps my user to also add a field called layout: and give my layout? Because right now it already uses the layout even though I don't specify it (doesn't load `index.jade` but the layout. Moreover, div= body what will take? the body of the given `.jade` file?

Comment: As I said in my message, layouts are enabled by default. So do res.render('index.jade', {user: usr, layout: false }) if you don't want the layout for a specific page, otherwise provide a value for layout. Body = the contents of the .jade file yes

Comment: Thanks a lot, where exactly did you read this? I searched around the jade website but couldn't really find something useful.

Comment: Check the first line of my message: http://expressjs.com/guide.html#view-rendering I've looked there. Also look at the end of my message, I gave you a link to a real application using jade.

Comment: This is correct. However, note that in common use case, you want to render the unescaped HTML, so you have to use != not =. I had to refer to the example to figure this out. Thanks for leading me to the answer.

Comment: @alessioalex http://expressjs.com/guide.html#view-rendering Link broken

Answer (score 7):

A little late to the party but I struggled to find the answer initially...
In layout.jade

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
    head
    body
        h1 Hello World
        block myblock
```

Then in index.jade

```
extends layout
    block myblock
        p Jade is cool
```

Will render

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <p>Jade is cool</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what does != body do? Need more details here.

Comment: @qodeninja - From the docs: "Unescaped buffered code starts with != and outputs the result of evaluating the JavaScript expression in the template. This does not do any escaping, so is not safe for user input"

Answer (score 4):

In express 3.x

Use Jade blocks, not layouts

http://www.devthought.com/code/use-jade-blocks-not-layouts/

Answer (score 1):

I know an approach that has given me the best results, even with angular (to substitute angular-route/ng-view)

First of all will be necessary to install express-layout:

```
npm install --save express-layout
```

After that, express will search for layout.jade file inside your *views/* folder. So, inside of that you can use:

**views/layout.jade**

```
html
  head
    meta(charset='utf-8')
    title= title
  body
    div!= body
```

**views/home.jade**

```
h1 Welcome aboard, matey!
```

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express'),
    layout = require('express-layout');

var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('home', {
    title: 'Welcome!'
});
```

By default express will search for layout.jade in your *views/* folder, but you can change the default, by using (yes, it is not necessary to write .jade extension):

```
app.set('layout', 'default');
```

After that express will use views/default.jade as the default layout.

Also if you want to use a different layout in a particular page, you can use:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('home', {
    layout: 'login',
    title: 'Welcome!'
});
```

Here express will render login.jade as the layout.

I suppose that you are using Jade as the default view engine, and don't change the default folder for views.

Here is the [express-layout doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-layout).