# Routes and scripts in Express (using Jade) - scripts on layout.jade

Tags: node.js, express

I am new to Node, Express, and Jade, and have a question about how to structure my script files.

In my layout I have jquery listed at the bottom. In another file, on another route, I wanted to add a script that uses jquery, so I wanted to add it below the jquery script tag on layout.jade when using that particular route.

layout.jade:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/happy.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/fonts.css')
    link(href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600', rel='stylesheet', type='text/css')
    link(href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600', rel='stylesheet', type='text/css')
    link(href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet")
    link(rel="icon" href="/favicon.png" sizes="16x16" type="image/png")
  body
    block content
    script(src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js')
    script(src="/javascripts/script.js")
```

I want this file added to the bottom of my scripts on the layout page when visting the /about route:

```
script(src="/javascripts/scroll.js")
```

/routes/about.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('about');
});

module.exports = router;
```

from app.js:

```
app.use('/about', about);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple layouts one with the script and one without

you set layouts like this

```
res.render('about', { layout: 'layoutwithscript.jade' });
```

Credit to @alessioalex in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402568/jade-template-engine-how-to-use-layout-jade)

Comment: thanks, is the res.render('about', { layout: 'layout_scroll.jade' }); put in the routes/about.js file? I modified it with this change and restarted npm, but it is still not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: @RonI are you calling that layout file from another .jade file if so then you could add a new block for extra scripts to the layout.jade and then in your about.jade add the script to that block